# Computing the probability that two values from two seperate lists are equal

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory

Let's say we have two lists A and B of equal length $L$ composed of uniformly random numbers, defined as follows:

$
A_i,B_i \in \mathbb{N} \\
A_i,B_i  \sim \mathcal{U}[0,K)
$

where $0 < i \le L$

The probability that two values, one from A and one from B at the same index $i$ are equal is given by:

$
Pr(A_i = B_i) = \frac{1}{L \times K^2}  \tag 1.
$

Simply put if G is equal to the probability of $m$-pairs of equal numbers at equal indicies, would it then be correct to say that G is equal to the following?

$
G= \prod_{i=1}^{m} \frac{1}{(L - i + 1) \times K^2}  \tag 2.
$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the list elements and the lists are independent then this is a Bernoulli trial with parameters $L$, $\frac1K$.

The probability that the $i^{\text{th}}$ elements equal is the same as that they both take value $1$ or value $2$ ... or value $K$; these are pairwise excluding events. So, $$P(A_i=B_i)=K\frac1{K^2}=\frac1K.$$

Then the probability that we have exactly $M$ paires matching is

$$\binom LM\left(\frac1K\right)^M\left(1-\frac1K\right)^{L-M}\tag 1.$$

---

Another interpretation

If we say that we randomly select an index  $I$ (with equal probabilities for $I=i, \ i=1,2...,L$) and consider the event that $A_I=B_I$ then the situation is not different. Then the probability that such a randomly selected pair is identical is

$$P(A_I=B_I)=\sum_{i=1}^LP(A_i=B_i\ \mid I=i)P(I=i)=L\frac1L\frac1{K}=\frac1{K}.$$

---

From this point on I cannot follow the OP. If we said that we repeat the latter experiment say $n$ times (with replacement) then we would have, again, a Bernoulli trial with parameters $n$ and $\frac1{K}$.

Comment: ah yes, seeing the problem as a Bernoulli trial is much more reasonable, thank-you.